# Why does angular allow dynamic object creation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm not sure if the title is correctly conveying the feature i'd like clarity on. But let me lay it out.

In javascript we can instantiate a variable to an empty object:

```
var person = {};
```

We can easily set properties to it

```
person.name = "Bob"
```

We can't, however, assign objects by using properties:

```
person.pet.name = "Bob"
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'name' of undefined
```

In angular you can. This modest code for example. I have a controller:

```
angular.module('someModule', [])
  .controller('someController', [
    Callback
  ]

function Callback(){
  this.person = {}
}
```

Then the view contains:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model='vm.person.pet.name'>
```

Where `vm` is the viewmodel representing the controller. When I log the results grabbed from the input you get a `person` object with a `pet` child object with a property of `name`

What gives? Why did angular add this feature?(i assume feature) Is it strictly for flexibility?

Comment: Yep, this is for flexibility and avoiding reference errors if pet does not exists yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression):

> **Forgiving**
>
> Expression evaluation is forgiving to undefined and null. In JavaScript, evaluating a.b.c throws an exception if a is not an object. While this makes sense for a general purpose language, the expression evaluations are primarily used for data binding, which often look like this:

```
{{a.b.c}}
```

> It makes more sense to show nothing than to throw an exception if a is undefined (perhaps we are waiting for the server response, and it will become defined soon). If expression evaluation wasn't forgiving we'd have to write bindings that clutter the code, for example: {{((a||{}).b||{}).c}}
>
> Similarly, invoking a function a.b.c() on undefined or null simply returns undefined.

In short, expression in html `<input type="text" data-ng-model='vm.person.pet.name'>` doesn't change in time, however an actual value of `vm.person.pet.name` does.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. It still bothers me a bit that a property can essentially instantiate a key for its grandparent object?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a feature. Imagine that you have an array of objects of different types e.g. people and animal.

people object:

```
{
   name: "someName",
   lastname: "someLastName
}
```

and

animal object:

```
{
   name: "someName"
   //Without lastname 
}
```

If you put an array of objects, which contains these 2 types of objects, to the ng-repeat you could easily avoid code crash if you try to access some property which is not part of the every object.